# Is it possible to hide branches in Azure DevOps for specific users ?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've been looking around on forums and on DevOps, but I seem to be unable to find where I can remove reading permissions for a certain user on a specific branch.

Or how I can hide a branch from an user or group. Is this actually possible or am I looking for something that doesn't exist ?

Help or advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how Git works.

Branches are just pointers to commits, so you can't "hide" a branch, because there's nothing that isolates a "commit" to a "branch".

If the goal is just convenience ("I don't want Team Foo to have their branch list cluttered with what Team Bar is working on"), it's a matter of branch organization. You can organize branches into "folders" by convention: Team A puts branches under `TeamA/`: `TeamA/featureX`, `TeamA/featureY`, etc. And Team B can do the same thing: `TeamB/z`. In most Git GUIs (and the Azure DevOps UI), that will create a nice collapsible hierarchy.

If the goal is isolation ("I want to put things into the repo that I don't want some people to be able to access under some circumstances"), then branches are not an appropriate method of achieving that kind of isolation.

Comment: yeah, now when i think about it - it doesnt make sense

Answer (score -2):

If it is a case of keeping source code private then you can put those in separate repositories. And then you can hide repositories from individual users assigned to that project.
To create a private repository the project admin can hide the repository from the users who are handling the project by following this :

Goto Repositories->Select Repo(Make sure that the user(s) that need to restricted are added to the project as members as well as on repo) -> Select user -> Set Read To Deny

[image: 1]

Comment: I've noticed this possibility as well, but I didn't think it was the right way to resolve my problem, that's the reason for my post.