# How to hide git feature branches from other team?

Tags: security, azure-devops, git-branch

I have a Azure DevOps Git repo on which two teams are currently working.
We created separate folders under 'feature/' for each team. Can we hide team1's feature folder from team-2?

Using [git tf permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops) command, I was able to restrict the contributory access to other team's folders. But I just don't want the feature team folder visible to other team members.

[Please click here to view my branch folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68mDN.png)

As per the image, team-1 members should be able to see only 'feature/team-1/*' branches. 'feature/team-2/*' should not be visible to team-1 people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to hide branches in Azure DevOps for specific users ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560134/is-it-possible-to-hide-branches-in-azure-devops-for-specific-users)

Comment: Yes & No. I understand what I am expecting is little tricky. But there should be some way. I tried deny:GenericRead access using git tf permission for other team, but still both feature folders are visible to each team.

Comment: Are you looking to just hide the folders in the Azure DevOps web UI or make the branches completely invisible also when the repository is cloned?

Comment: hiding only in devOps webUI

Comment: I can't imagine why it would matter if different teams can see what the other teams are working on if they're both contributing to the same code base. That said, in order to accomplish what you want, one of the teams should probably work out of a fork of the repo and submit PRs back to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's NOT supported to hide specific branch for other team in Azure DevOps UI.

It's only supported to hide specific repo for one team, but cannot for branch level.